Grafana, getting the same IP several times in table
I`m trying to display switch status in Grafana.
To get the data I am using prometheus and smtp_exporter.
I am able to access the data in Grafana. The probem is when I try to get a table with the status, I get the same IP several times in the table view.
im using this query:
max_over_time(up{job="snmp"}[5m])

I have also just tried with:
up{job="snmp"}

I have also added series to row.
Is there any way to avoid this / filter it?

What do you mean? Same IP and time? Or just IP with different timestamps?

you can use offset as [5m] is not calculating the first milliseconds:
max_over_time(up{job="snmp"}[5m] offset -5m)


Can you explain what you mean by your answer a bit more, and how it is expected to solve the problem at hand?
